# Repeating Content On Web Page

Tags: asp.net, html

What is the best way to include repeating content on every page of a website such as a navigation menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET master pages are the way to go. Here's some resources to get you started:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET, you could use either [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) or [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)

Comment: Nice call on user controls. Very helpful when master pages aren't practical!